# How can I determine if a dataset is zFS

Tags: zos

What z/OS control block can I query to determine if a dataset is of type zFS?  all other file types can be determined by looking at flags in the F1DSECT control block, but I don't see anything about zFS there.

Comment: I don't think zFS is it's own data set type. The zFS file system is implemented using a VSAM Linear Data Set.

Comment: ok, well then is there a way to tell if a linear dataset is living in a zFS file system?  the DSCB control blocks has a field named DS1SMSFG  "SYSTEM MANAGED STORAGE INDICATORS" that indicates amoung other things indicates if a dataset is part of a HFS system. I'm looking for a similar flag for zFS.

Comment: DS1SMSFG can be used if the data set is an HFS or a ZFS, the two are interchangeable. HFS (hierarchical file system) if the DS1PDSE and DS1PDSEX bits are on.

Comment: Dave, thanks for this info! just to clarify, if a datset is in an HFS or ZFS, the  DS1PDSEX bit will be on. and if the DS1PDSEX and DS1PDSE bits on are it is HFS, otherwise it is ZFS?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I may have given you bad advice. Both bits must be set on for an HFS but the VTOC won't tell you if a VSAM data set is a zFS as Ross mentioned. To be sure you will need to query the mouted file systems using [w_getmntent (BPX1GMN, BPX4GMN)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxb100/gmn.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can answer the question just by looking at the bits in the VTOC. At minimum, I think you'll need to call IGGCSI00 and check for FSDSFLAG to detect a zFS.

There's also a UNIX Services way...

If the filesystem you're looking at is mounted (in the UNIX Services sense), one solution is to use the w_getmntent() or BPX1GMN service. If you happen to know the mount point (from a path on the filesystem, etc), you can go directly to it - otherwise, you can iterate through the mount points until you find the one matching the dataset name you're looking for. From there, the output from BPX1GMN (see the BPXYMNTE macro) has most of the information you'll need to understand the filesystem type.

If you need deeper information, there's also the w_statvfs() and pfsctl() functions. Not sure what you'd do if the filesystem isn't mounted, however.